# Trying to create a Password Generator that can save passwords

Tags: python, sqlite, password-generator

I have created the baseline of the program, and it works well, but I want it to be able to save the password generations, and store them under an index name in SQLite. I want it to be so that I can always access the previously generated passwords.

Code:

```
    def gen_password():
        letters = string.ascii_letters
        random_letter = random.choice(letters)
        random_num = random.randint(0,9)
        letter_or_num = ["letter","number"]
        char_num = int(input("How many characters do you want in your password?: "))
        for i in range(char_num):
            random_var = random.choice(letter_or_num)
            if random_var == "letter":
                random_letter = random.choice(letters)
                print(random_letter, end = "")
            elif random_var == "number":
                random_num = random.randint(0,9)
                print(random_num, end = "")
        print("")
    
    gen_password()
```

Comment: Is your question how to write data to a sqlite database? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem:

```
def gen_password():
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    random_letter = random.choice(letters)
    random_num = random.randint(0,9)
    letter_or_num = ["letter","number"]
    char_num = int(input("How many characters do you want in your password?: "))
   
    password = []
    for i in range(char_num):
        random_var = random.choice(letter_or_num)
        if random_var == "letter":
            random_letter = random.choice(letters)
            # replace print with this:
            password.append(random_letter)  
         
        elif random_var == "number":
            random_num = random.randint(0,9)
            password.append(str(random_num))
    return "".join(password)

print(gen_password())
```

Comment: That definitely helps to have a list, but the issue is that the passwords don't save, and I want to find a way to use SQLite to store the passwords in a database that the code can always access and refer back to.

Comment: I guess you want to save created passwords in SQLite database. Here is youtube link for you if you are new to SQLite. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd-0G0MigUA